# can't get my .bat file to exit loop and go to a menu

Tags: loops, batch-file, menu, break

So, I've created a .bat file that checks a series of standard servers to see if they are up, and I want to create options based on the results after it's complete. The batch runs great, until I throw in the menu. Halp?

```
@echo off
:top
cd\
cls
SET site=%1
SET cc=%2
if "%site%" equ "" set /P site=Site Number:&SET /P cc=Country Code (US if left blank):
if [%cc%]==[] set cc=us
echo.

:startloop
set #=%site%
:subloop
set site=s0%site%

echo Checking %site%.%cc%
echo.

for %%i in (saps01 saps02 vsrv01 vsrv02) do call :main %%i
echo.
goto end


:main
set sys=%1.%site%.%cc%
set state=down
ping -n 1 -w 2000 %sys% | findstr "Reply" >Nul
if %errorlevel% equ 0 set state=up
if %state% equ "down" goto main2

:main2
echo %1 is %state%


goto end

:end

set /p menu=Select an option:

echo 1) option 1
echo 2) option 2

if %menu%=1 echo 1
if %menu%=2 echo 2
```

Comment: Please be more specific about what the problem is. What *does* happen, and how does that differ from what you expected?

Comment: Your menu input is in the middle of a call procedure - it all seems a little unwieldy.  Do you want to check if several servers are online, and then proceed if they are all online?  Or...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified your code to simplify it - see if it helps you at all:

```
@echo off
:top
cd\
cls
SET "site=%1"
SET "cc=%2"

if "%site%" equ "" (
   set /P "site=Site Number: "
   set /P "cc=Country Code (US if left blank): "
)
if "%cc%"=="" set "cc=us"

:startloop
set #=%site%
:subloop
set site=s0%site%

echo Checking %site%.%cc%
echo.

for %%i in (saps01 saps02 vsrv01 vsrv02) do (
ping -n 1 -w 2000 %%i.%site%.%cc% >nul && (echo %%i is up) || (echo %%i is down)
echo.
)

echo 1) option 1
echo 2) option 2

set /p "menu=Select an option: "


if "%menu%"=="1" echo 1
if "%menu%"=="2" echo 2

goto :where?
```

Answer (score 2):

I would move the `set` command after the option headings and use `==` instead of `=`

```
echo 1) option 1
echo 2) option 2

set /p menu=Select an option:

if %menu%==1 echo 1
if %menu%==2 echo 2
```